# HTML form submit to PHP script with associative array

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I'm making an HTML form. I want the results to appear in the PHP script on another page.

Here is my form :

```
echo '<form name="form1" action="page2.php" method="post">';
echo '<SELECT name="choice">';
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
echo '<OPTION VALUE="'.$value.'" name="'.$value.'">'.$key.'</OPTION>';
```

Now, on my page2.php I want to retrieve both $key AND $value using the "post" method, I tried these 3 solutions one by one and it failed :

```
echo $_POST["choice"]; //nothing
echo $_POST[$key];     //nothing
echo $_POST[$value];   //nothing
```

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a delimiter in the value of your options like this:

```
echo '<form name="form1" action="page2.php" method="post">';
echo '<SELECT name="choice">';
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
echo '<OPTION VALUE="'.$key.'|'.$value.'" >'.$value.'</OPTION>';
```

and then, on post, retrieve it this way:

```
$expldedArray = explode("|", $_POST["choice"]);
$key = $expldedArray[0];
$value = $expldedArray[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

You dont need to give a name to the option in select field. Just give a name to the select tag like below:

```
echo '<form name="form1" action="page2.php" method="post">';
echo '<SELECT name="choice">';
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
       echo '<OPTION VALUE="'.$value.'">'.$key.'</OPTION>';
```

and then in your php code after selecting a value and submitting the form:

```
echo $_POST['choice']
```

will give you the selected value.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {

     echo ucfirst($key); echo " = "; 
     if(is_array($value))
          echo implode(",", $value);
     else
          echo $value; 

     echo '<br />';
}
```

Where `ucfirst()` capitalizes first letter of string.
`implode()` will glue array elements with given string